# Integrate VBulletin in a J2EE application and support single sign on

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, single-sign-on, vbulletin

I am considering purchasing VBulletin and integrating it with my J2EE application. While I am still looking into what it takes to enable this integration, I was wondering if VBulletin supports single sign on so that my users do not have to login to VBulletin once they have been authenticated to the application. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

<strike>STFW</strike>Google is your friend! Seriously, why don't you just look at its vBulletin [features](http://www.vbulletin.com/index.php?do=features) (especially if you are considering purchasing it):

> Single Member Sign-on     Yes     Yes

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, it doesn't appear that VBulletin supports SSO across other applications that it might integrate with. Bummer.

Answer (score 0):

vbulletin does not support `SSO` as far as I know. We were trying to integrate `JIRA / Crowd` with vbulletin, but the vbulletin php guys are living in an ancient era, no support for `SSO` or `openid` or any other form on integration.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK none of the PHP based forum apps support true single sign on. Have you considered a java based forum like [JForum](http://jforum.net/index.jsp) which does support SSO and with a bit of work it can be made to work with most SSO platforms (OpenId, [Cloudseal](http://www.cloudseal.com), [CAS](http://www.jasig.org/cas) etc)